# Binary classification with unexplained data

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

My apologies for cross-posting to stackoverflow and cross validated. Not really sure which one is the most relevant place.

Please shed some light on me with this task.

### Description

Assuming the training data looks like

```
0 | X773579,Y2640,Y2072,Z4,Z15
1 | X374616379,X773579,X344420902,Y1940,Y1705,Z4,Z15,Z26
...
```

One would like to predict 0/1 from those comma separated values, without further explanation about what exactly the X, Y, and Z with numbers mean. Some rare cases even have un-numbered X or Y (possibly just noises though). The length of comma separated values varies, but each row contains no repeated values. Also, the length of numbers seem correlated to X, Y, and Z.

The data size is 1 million rows.

### Feature

In LibSVM format

```
Label | Value_ID:1...
```

Example

```
0 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1
1 1:1 4:1 5:1 14:1 36:1 37:1 38:1 39:1
```

I've tried treating those values categorically and applying several different models of Spark MLlib, namely linear regression, logistic regression, decision tree, random forests, gradient-boosted trees, and SVM, along with LibSVM and Conditional Random Fields. Their 5-fold cross-validations got only 75%~79% accuracy.

I really want to know if there's any formal way to discover the signal from the data, build up models, extract and even select features accordingly. Admittedly I haven't done ANOVA yet.

Thank you!

### Background (self-disclosure)

This is a private interview question and the employer didn't share any details (except "no offer" response :p). Although I specifically asked twice that I would like to learn from it, no reply so far.

### Book studying/studied

- Pattern classification
- Pattern recognition
- Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing
- Speech and Language Processing

### What I may try next

Based on a discussion with @NeilSlater :

I have done some quick frequent pattern analysis and found certain n-grams. The problem was that they seemed associated with both labels 0 and 1. I will run some feature templates of bi-gram and tri-gram, and then get back to you. One thing that is also intriguing to me is, in NLP, sometimes labels also got dependencies, namely some 1 may be followed by certain patterns of 0 and vice versa.

### Updates

In terms of linear/logistic regressions and conditional random fields:

1. n-gram is slightly harmful: tried adjacent bigram/trigram & pair/triple combinations, all got worse about 1%
2. occurrences of X/Y/Z & mean/max/min/sum/avg of X/Y/Z can only reach 69%.
3. X or Y or Z solely as categorical feature got 70%~75%. Y is the most useful category.

Other models listed in the original description all got far worse results.

Comment: Looks a bit like tokenised words with each row being a sentence. Of course it may not be, but perhaps techniques that worked with that data would work well with this?

Comment: @NeilSlater: That's what I thought. I've converted those values to binary features. Will update the post to indicate it.

Comment: Sine the cross-posts are being processed (my apologies again), I would like to keep track on a comment from @cel :

_What is a `formal way`? A fixed recipe? There's no such thing in machine learning and even general principles how to tackle such a problem will be highly opinion based._

Comment: My reply:
I totally agree, just wondering if there's something I don't know. In fact I dislike this task in the first place since it doesn't feel like a properly defined one.

Comment: As well as binary features for categories, the sequence might be important. It may be worth checking if you have a range of n-grams that occur repeatedly, as that would be a strong indicator that approaches used in NLP could help - even a simple approach such as creating new feature categories for most common n-grams might give you something.

Comment: @NeilSlater : Indeed. I have done some quick frequent pattern analysis and found certain n-grams. The problem was that they seemed associated with both labels 0 and 1. I will run some feature templates of bi-gram and tri-gram, and then get back to you. One thing that is also intriguing to me is, in NLP, sometimes labels also got dependencies, namely some 1 may follow by certain patterns of 0 and vice versa.

Comment: Have you looked at the distribution of numerical values for each X, Y, and Z?

Comment: @jamesmf : Not thoroughly but it did cross my mind. Will do it, too. At first glance X, Y, Z seem usually being with >6 figures, 4-6 figures, and 1-3 figures, respectively.

Comment: I strongly agree that NLP-based methods could work here, but if the data seem more continuous, you might try constructing features based on the X,Y,Z values.  It would be interesting to plot the positive/negative examples vs. mean(X), mean(Y), mean(Z) or vs max(X), max(Y), max(Z).  If any of those seem somewhat separable, it could give hints to how the data were generated.

Another route to go if the data takes on a large space numerically would be to bin it.  If you were to use NLP methods after binning, it would be similar to stemming

Comment: Re: cross-posting. I'm not sure what is the best way to handle this question, considering existing discussion on both CV and this site. IMHO this question definitely doesn't belong to StackOverflow, but between CV and Data Science, I think it better fits this site. So, from the moderation perspective, perhaps, my fellow moderators could chime in and share their opinion on the best course of action. CC: @SeanOwen

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh : thank you very much and sorry for the mess. Either way, I will do my best to keep track on comments by manually posting them.

Comment: @jamesmf : Yes, and that's why I also took a strange (?) choice to try conditional random fields with only unigram, and yet it's the best so far (about 79%). I will continue trying bigram/trigram and also several polynomial ways with those numerical values.

Comment: @jamesmf : Speaking of binning, one of my usual tactic is to convert numerical numbers by log2, but not done yet, will get back to you once I completed it.

Comment: @Barabbas: You are welcome and no problem.